# Select nth-of-type in current row with no IDs (.NET repeater)

Tags: jquery, .net, webforms

jQuery has been haunting me the last couple of days.  I just can't seem to get into the selector mindset.

In a .NET application, I've created a user control which dynamically creates rows using a repeater (so I can't just select IDs, or even Client IDs for that matter), so generally I've been jumping up to the parent row that contains the control and firing events based on selectors within that row.

For this example, I'm firing an event onchange of a dropdown index.  This event will enable / disable a textbox based on the year selected in the Launch Year dropdown. In the event, I perform a loop, starting at the start year (a hidden field on the page), and loop until start year + 15, and disable / enable accordingly.  Any years prior to the selected Launch Year should be disabled.

Here is the control: [image]

And below is the code.  But first, let me include a short snippet of what I'm really trying to achieve.  There's probably a WAY easier method, I'm just a jQuery novice.

First, I get the parent row of the dropdown that just fired:

```
var parentRow = $this.closest('tr');
```

Then I want to get the nth-of-type textbox, using the year index, and disable / enable accordingly.  This is clearly not working at all, performing really slowly, and baffling me.

```
$(parentRow.attr("id") + "input[type=text]type:nth-of-type(" + (i - startYear) + ")").attr('disabled', '');
```

Full function below:

```
 function LaunchChanged(ddl) {
    var $this = $(ddl);
    var parentRow = $this.closest('tr');
    //alert("Value is " + ddl.value + "\n Old Value is " + ddl.oldvalue);

    if ($this.attr("id").indexOf('Year') != -1) {
        if ($this.val() == -1) {
            DisableTextBoxes(parentRow);
            ClearTextBoxes(parentRow);
        } else {
            var startYear = $("input[type=hidden][id*='hfStartYear']").val();

            for (var i = startYear; i <= startYear + 15 ; i++) {
                if (i >= $this.val()) {
                    $(parentRow.attr("id") + "input[type=text]type:nth-of-type(" + (i - startYear) + ")").attr('disabled', '');
                } else {
                    $(parentRow.attr("id") + "input[type=text]:nth-of-type(" + (i - startYear) + ")").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //ShowModalPopup();
}
```

Per request, .NET repeater code shown below:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTotalSales" ItemType="CHIPS.Entities.SalesControl">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" ID="row">
                <td>
                    <span runat="server" ID="expandButton" class="pointer" Visible="False">+</span>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked='<%#Item.IsActivated%>' ID="cbActivated"/>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRegionName" Text='<%#Item.RegionName%>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSubRegionName" Text='<%#Item.SubRegionName%>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="LaunchChanged(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" runat="server" ID="ddlLaunchMonth" AppendDataBoundItems="True"/></td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="LaunchChanged(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" runat="server" ID="ddlLaunchYear" AppendDataBoundItems="True"/></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear1)%>' ID="txtSalesYear1"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear2)%>' ID="txtSalesYear2"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear3)%>' ID="txtSalesYear3"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear4)%>' ID="txtSalesYear4"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear5)%>' ID="txtSalesYear5"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear6)%>' ID="txtSalesYear6"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear7)%>' ID="txtSalesYear7"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear8)%>' ID="txtSalesYear8"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear9)%>' ID="txtSalesYear9"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear10)%>' ID="txtSalesYear10"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear11)%>' ID="txtSalesYear11"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear12)%>' ID="txtSalesYear12"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear13)%>' ID="txtSalesYear13"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear14)%>' ID="txtSalesYear14"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox Enabled="<%#Item.IsActivated%>" runat="server" Text='<%#:String.Format("{0:f4}", Item.SalesYear15)%>' ID="txtSalesYear15"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>                    
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.RegionID%>' ID="hfRegionID"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.SubRegionID%>' ID="hfSubRegionID"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.LaunchMonth%>' ID="hfLaunchMonth"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.LaunchYear%>' ID="hfLaunchYear"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.Gate0ActualDate%>' ID="hfGate0ActualDate"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.HasChild%>' ID="hfHasChild"/>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.ProjectID%>' ID="hfProjectID" />
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Item.StartYear%>' ID="hfStartYear" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What's your repeater look like, are these asp:textboxes or inputs? I ask because you should add an attribute like `data-year=xxxx` and `data-parentid=xx` to them directly. Then your jQuery selectors can be exact: `$('input[data-parentid='+id+'][data-year='+year+']')`...

Comment: These are asp:textboxes as I need to be able to perform server side events with them.  I've posted the repeater source in the original post.

Comment: That's a great idea, I think I'll do that on repeater DataBound event.